# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I had uploaded my app to Google Play (back when it was called Android Market) some time ago.

Today I updated the app, but I had deleted the previous keystore and created a new one.
When uploading, it says the APK must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version:

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>
> Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 89:2F:11:FE:CE:D6:CC:DF:65:E7:76:3E:DD:A7:96:4F:84:DD:BA:33 ]
>   and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 20:26:F4:C1:DF:0F:2B:D9:46:03:FF:AB:07:B1:28:7B:9C:75:44:CC ]

But I don't have this certificate, and don't want to delete and re-publish the application, because it has active users.

What can I do to sign my app with new certificate?

Comment: I'm having a different issue: I tried to upgrade an app but it keeps me saying this error. The fact is, I've never changed the keystore!!! What can I do?!?

Comment: how did you solved??

Comment: @int_32 how u solve it??

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Nothing. Read the documentation: [Publishing Updates on Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketupgrade)

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the  element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and **the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.**

Comment: Great answer. I never realized that if key is lost then app can not be updated. Must keep in mind to backup the key in secure place.

Comment: What?! But it just told me my key was too old so i deleted it and created a new one now I get this!?

Comment: @iwayneo The build system might have told you that your **debug** key was too old, but that's very unlikely to have happened with a **release** key, since Google Play should reject keys that expire before [October 2033](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-keys).

Comment: This is no longer true, you cannot upload a new apk if the signed cert has changed

Comment: Is there anyone who solved this issue, becz i already done each & every step as per above answer but i can't update my app and google showing me same response like above question.

Comment: @rubycon can you clarify what is meant exactly with `package name` ?

Comment: @mesqueeb it's about 'com.company.appname' part

Answer (score 146):

### Did you sign with the debug key by mistake?

Google Play does not allow you to publish an app signed with your debug keystore.  If you try to upload such an APK, Google Play will fail with the message "You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode."

However, if you try to upload an *update* which is signed with the debug keystore, you will *not* see this message; Google Play will display the message shown in the question, referring to SHA1 fingerprints.

So firstly, check whether you signed the app with your debug key by mistake.

---

### How do I check which signing keys were used?

#### Gather the information from the APK

You can check which certificates the original APK and update APK were signed with by using these commands, using the Java `keytool`:

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile original.apk
keytool -printcert -jarfile update.apk
```

This shows you detailed information about the how an APK was signed, for example:

```
Owner: CN=My App, O=My Company, L=Somewhere, C=DE
Issuer: CN=My App, O=My Company, L=Somewhere, C=DE
Serial number: 4790b086
Valid from: Mon Nov 11 15:01:28 GMT 2013 until: Fri Mar 29 16:01:28 BST 2041
Certificate fingerprints:
  MD5:  A3:2E:67:AF:74:3A:BD:DD:A2:A9:0D:CA:6C:D4:AF:20
  SHA1: A6:E7:CE:64:17:45:0F:B4:C7:FC:76:43:90:04:DC:A7:84:EF:33:E9
  SHA256: FB:6C:59:9E:B4:58:E3:62:AD:81:42:...:09:FC:BC:FE:E7:40:53:C3:D8:14:4F
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3
```

The important parts to note here — for each APK — are the **SHA1** fingerprint value, the **Owner** identity value, and the **Valid from/until** dates.

---

If that `keytool` command doesn't work (the `-jarfile` option requires Java 7), you can get more basic information via the `jarsigner` command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose:summary -certs original.apk
jarsigner -verify -verbose:summary -certs update.apk
```

This unfortunately does not show the SHA1 fingerprint, but does show the X.509 owner identity, along with the certificate expiry dates. For example:

```
sm  4642892 Thu Apr 17 10:57:44 CEST 2014 classes.dex (and 412 more)

    X.509, CN=My App, O=My Company, L=Somewhere, C=DE
    [certificate is valid from 11/11/13 12:12 to 29/03/41 12:12]
    [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]
```

You can ignore any "CertPath not validated" message, along with warnings about certificate chains or timestamps; they're not relevant in this case.

#### Compare the Owner, SHA1 and Expiry values between the APKs

- If the **Owner**/**X.509** identity value is **`CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US`**, then you have signed the APK with your **debug key**, not the original release key
- If the **SHA1** fingerprint value is different between the original and update APKs, then you did **not** use the same signing key for both APKs
- If the **Owner**/**X.509** identity values are different, or the certificate expiry dates differ between the two APKs, then you did **not** use the same signing key for both APKs

Note that even if the Owner/X.509 values are identical between the two certificates, this doesn't mean that the certificates are identical — if anything else does not match — such as the fingerprint values — then the certificates are different.

---

### Search for the original keystore, check backups

If the two APKs have different certificate information, then you *must* find the original keystore, i.e. the file with the first SHA1 fingerprint value that Google Play (or `keytool`) told you.

Search through all the keystore files you can find on your computer, and in any backups you have, until you have the one with the correct SHA1 fingerprint:

```
keytool -list -keystore my-release.keystore
```

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> if prompted for the password — you don't necessarily have to enter it if you just want to quickly check the SHA1 value.

---

### I can't find the original keystore anywhere

If you cannot find the original keystore, you will **never** be able to publish any updates to this particular app.

Android mentions this explicitly on the [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode) page:

> **Warning:** Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. *If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.*

**After the first release of an APK, all subsequent releases must be signed with the exact same key.**

---

### Can I extract the original signing key from the original APK?

No. This is not possible. The APK only contains public information, and not your private key information.

---

### Can I migrate to a new signing key?

No. Even if you do find the original, you can't sign an APK with key A, then sign the next update with both keys A and B, then sign the next update after that with only key B.

Signing an APK (or any JAR file) with multiple keys is *technically* possible, but Google Play no longer accepts APKs with multiple signatures.

Attempting to do so will result in the message "Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again."

---

### What can I do?

You will have to build your app with a new application ID (e.g. change from "com.example.myapp" to "com.example.myapp2") and create a brand new listing on Google Play.

Possibly you will also have to change your code so that people can install the new app even if they have the old app installed, e.g. you need to make sure that you don't have conflicting content providers.

You will lose your existing install base, reviews etc., and will have to find a way to get your existing customers to uninstall the old app and install the new version.

Again, ensure you have secure backups of the keystore and password(s) you use for this version.

Comment: I've tried the command you gave, for checking for debug (which I was actually searching for), but it returns an error that the jar contains signatures that do not include a timestamp. I created my apk using this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio

Comment: @RageCompex Do you get no output and only an error? When I run that command, I also get a timestamp warning (not an error). So long as you get the X.509 output, that's all you need.

Comment: Yes, I do get the X.509 output, so it is not a problem I guess? What about `[CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]`, not a problem eather? I do see my name at `CN` so I guess I properly signed it :)

Comment: @RageCompex This is already answered in the "Check the signing keys used" section.

Comment: I had a mini heart attack today. I used these command lines to figure out the hidden Keystore. Thanks a lot, man! You saved me...  Really :D

Answer (score 16):

Nothing - Google says it clearly that the application is identified by the keys used to sign it. Consequently if you've lost the keys, you need to create a new application.

Comment: @sports They **do** warn you. Notice the big red **Warning** message: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode

Comment: @sports In any case, you can publish more than one app on the same developer account, so you don't need to pay again.

Answer (score 12):

I just had this occur out of the clear blue.  I really do not think I changed anything.

However, `Build => Clean Project` fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, I've been spending 1 week, did everything possible. and it's time to say "WTF", but it's the only thing that helped. (I've also tried invalidate caches that didnt help..) Thanks

Comment: This fixed the issue after going crazy for one hour

Comment: I don't see this is related.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I accidentally generated a signed apk with different keystore file and credentials and uploaded it. Kept getting the same error even after uploading apk with correct keystore. After an hour of creating new releases with invalidate cache,android studio and PC restarts, this finally fixed it.

Comment: After lot of hit and trial, I come to this answer and magically it's worked for me, but still figuring out how!!

Comment: how could you do it on vscode? I think i have similar issue

Answer (score 7):

Today i faced same issue, unfortunately, i was having two aliases in my keystore file.[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here i get the answer for that question . After searching for too long finally i get to crack the key and password for this . I forget my key and alias also the jks file but fortunately i know the bunch of password what i had put in it . but finding correct combinations for that was toughest task for me .

Solution - 
 Download this - Keytool IUI version 2.4.1 plugin
[image]

the window will pop up now it show the alias name ..if you jks file is correct .. 
right click on alias and hit "view certificates chain "..
it will show the SHA1 Key .. match this key with tha key you get while you was uploading the apk in google app store ...

if it match then you are with the right jks file and alias ..

now lucky i have bunch of password to match .. 
[image]

now go to this scrren put the same jks path .. and password(among the password you have ) put any path in  "Certificate file"

if the screen shows any error then password is not matching .. if it doesn't show any error then it means you are with correct jks file . correct alias and password() 
now with that you can upload your apk in play store :)

Comment: you lost the private key and you were able to retrieve it this way? If the answer is yes, is it possible for you to link where to download the tool? And how do I open the app?

Comment: Works like a charm, and served my purpose. Thanks for the share.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend Keystore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/) which lets you access your keystore without having to upload it to Google Play. This way you can troubleshoot whether you are entering your password incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

Please check your `android/app/build.gradle` file for

```
android{
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

before releasing the appbundle, It should have the `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` this line enabled instead of `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` this line.

I made this silly mistake.

I was testing my updated app on other devices by releasing it with the `debug sign in config` and when I was ready to publish the update I didn't change the config and released the bundle which had the debug config.

After scratching my head for around an hour I realized that I had this `debug config` all the time then I changed it to `release mode` now the problem is solved.

Comment: its kinda not help any one here, but after updating react-native version and many files changed, that was the problem for me, the update overwrite on the  "signingConfigs.release"   to be "signingConfigs. debug"

Comment: I had updated react native and all the packages, and forgot to change this line again. that was my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If you have previous apk file with you(backup) then use jarSigner to extract certificate from that that apk, then use that key or use keytool to clone that certificate, may be that will help...
Helpful links are [jarsigner docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) and [keytool docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html).

Comment: "..use jarSigner to extract certificate from that apk" - Tell us how to do this?

Comment: That will not recover the private key you'd need to sign the apk again.

Comment: Apk must be signed with same private key

Answer (score 1):

My [silly] mistake was that i used app-debug.apk file instead of app-release.apk file.
You need to to choose "release" in "Build Variants" frame when you generate signed APK.
The app-release.apk file should be located under "app\release" folder in your project root.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue recently, after trying different ways to sign in like enable V1 Or V2, signed in by changing alias name and **last come to know that I am using wrong key store file**

Answer (score 0):

You can use new feature Google play app signing to generate a new key file .

After May 2017 Google play store add a new feature on Play store and
It’s Good News For Android Developers.
From this feature, Developer can update their app or Apk who lost a KeyStore file.
you need to enable google play app signing on play store console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

http://www.geekcodehub.com/2018/05/23/keystore-lost-in-android/

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I realized I had previously uploaded an .aab file and I was now trying to upload .apk file. I just needed to check *Build App Bundle (Google Play)* on build settings

Answer (score 0):

**For Flutter Developers:**
You need to reverify key.properties file.

- android/key.properties

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Select Sign-in key(locate top of AppBundle text) and select Release signed by google
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the .jks file is created, the system time should not be ahead of the upload time.