# Changing android app certificate

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this message: The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version. 
I read this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

But here is my dilemma.
This app was created by another developer. So i have all the files from him. Now i updated the app i am trying to upload it to market its giving me this error. Is there anyway to get this from project files i have from previous version of the app? By what name will this file be saved on the previous version? How can i reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to get the release key for 1st version of that application. Otherwise u cant put into that app into the market.
Because for all version of same app it requires same release key.

Comment: where will i find the release key on the project usually?

Comment: It will be with the previous developer. Just ask him

Comment: He has given me all the file and the whole folder for the app. Any idea what should i look for to see if i already have it?

Comment: check there any file like name--->appname-release-key.keystore

Comment: Do i just need the release-key file or do i need the password of that keystore also? Where will i add this file on my new folder?

Comment: no its no need to add anywhere. Bcz to put an app into the market we need a signed apk, for that we need that key. So just use that key to create signed apk from ur apk. and put into the market. Thats it