# Update app on Google Play

Tags: android, upload, apk

I have recently uploaded an app in Android Market. I have fixed some of the issues and now trying to upload the latest version. I am sure i am using `same keystore`, same packages, higher version code. When uploading, it shows following error:

```
The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version.
```

EDIT:
I have regenerated apk with same keystore, this time error changed:

```
The server could not process your apk. Try again.
```

Comment: You're signing it *exactly* the same way as before? Same keystore? Same credentials, etc.? They have to be absolutely the same.

Comment: I am sure its same @BryanDenny

Comment: Do not post the repeated questions. Refer this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version

Comment: But that didnot solve my problem @androidexpert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with the Google's server. I changed my package names and uploaded it as new and fresh app.