# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have uploaded on apk file on the google play account,
apk i have created from eclipse by right click on the project and export and put following details in it
password,alias and developer units only.

and i have uploaded successfully on google play account.
But now problem is i have deleted this apk from local and also i am unable to uplaod any other apk if try to update 2nd apk with version code = 2 and version name = 1.0 then also it is giving me error that
**The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version.**

So please help me to solve this issue now what can i do to upload a new updated apk in this application.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the app and republish it with the same id and different keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the same keystore file to sign your apks.

> the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.

Taken from here,

[The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843212/603744)

The only way is to sign your update package apk with the same key which you have used for the previous version. No other go. Google is strict about it.

Comment: yes i have refer this question that you have mentioned but i wrote keystore "123456" thought it is giving me error dont know why.

and if i mismatch something then is there other way to overcome this problem and update the apk?

Comment: what if the keystore file is lost,is there any way to sign apk

Answer (score 0):

> For the same application you are updating it's version. Then there is
>   no need of having previous apk file but there should be same keystore
>   which you have used to sign the first apk file which is on google
>   play. Also follow the same steps which you have done for first apk
>   file.

In case you don't have same keystore then :( you simply cannot update the same application as of now.