# Switch a native existing app with cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, app-store, cordova-3, google-play

I'm trying to update an existing native app (actually are two: one for iOS and one for Android) switching all the content with cordova.
Basically I need to rewrite the app with cordova but I also would like to update the same app instead of asking to users to uninstall the old one and install back the new one.
Is it possible? Any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the most part you will need to re-write the app, but if you use the same namespace and signing keys, it should allow an update

Comment: Yes, I would really love to rewrite everything from the ground up since I am more comfortable with the cli workflow of cordova and I would use the same package name and keys but some developer pointed me out that something could go wrong and I was wondering if I should follow some particular method.

Comment: I can't speak from personal experience but I know that apps like facebook and twitter moved from HTML5 to native and no one had to reinstall or install a different app. So I am fairly certain it should work. I think apple may take an issue if the functionality has drastically changed, but as long as the app is visually/functionally the same (or very similar) it should pass.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely try!

Comment: Maybe this will help you with the android signing process:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015013/swap-existing-native-app-with-a-cordova-phonegap-based-one-without-the-user-know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just need to use the same app ids as the native apps used on android/ios (define them in you cordova config.xml) - and for android you need to sign the final apk using the original `*.keystore` file.

Comment: I have the same issue as Enrico's. During development, I am using a different package name than the existing native app package name. So before launching my cordova app to the store, can I just change the package name in XCode and build the app?

Comment: You should change it in the cordova `config.xml`

Comment: Ok. Does it have to do anything with the Provisioning Profile and developer certificates?

Comment: no. Use the same package id as the native app - and on ios the app will just be overwritten.

Comment: thanks mwager! this really helped me gaining confidence. There is time to do this, but I started an early investigation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that as long as you use the same package name and keys chances are that you can update your current app. Great!