# Apk file update in Google play store

Tags: android

I have a android apps in google play store and i want to update this apps with some good feature.
I have made my apk and when i want to update my apps google say's that You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
How i can solve it.

Comment: are you using the same certificate to sign the app?

Comment: use same key store as you created while uploading your apk first time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the app with the same certificate as your original app. Thats how Google Play verifies that it is an authentic app, and not malicious.

Answer (score 0):

When you export an app, you sign it with a keystore.
If you want to upload a new version of your app, you must upload it using the same keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the 'build.gradle (module:app)' file 
and
you need to increase 'versionCode' for new update version.