# upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs

Tags: android, google-play

I need to update my app in google play store, but I generated apk file on another computer that the previous one. I used the same keystore file `(lazymojo.jsk)` and I get an error about using different SHA1 certificate. Then I switched to my old pc where i made the first version and generate signed `apk`, but it gives me the same error again.

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 58:EA:40:73:F8:0E:7F:07:A7:0B:C3:EE:FB:FA:22:50:18:CF:53:4E ]
>   and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 6F:12:B6:7B:7F:55:8C:F9:98:B3:78:41:8A:9E:EB:E6:99:7B:91:45 ]

I used same keystore  file and password.

Please help me i am new in android developing. Thanks in ad=vance

Comment: are you sure they are the same? Your SHA1's are different meaning they are different certificates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Comment: They are clearly two different certificates, SHA don't lie. Maybe you misplaced the file

Comment: i face the same problem..having same credential with diff pc.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you have used the same Key alias as well. I faced the same error when changed Key alias to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me (but you should find your original keystore)

1. Download your orginal apk from play store
2. Deplace your apk to java\jdk...\bin
3. Open cmd windows and move to the directory with where your file apk
4. Execute this comand "keytool -list-printcert -jarfile yourfile.apk"
   this command will return all infrmation about your file apk
   (keystore and password)
5. Find your keystore (.jks)
6. Generate your new apk from your  keystore

Comment: keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourfile.apk  This worked for me in a different way, allowed me to see the date of the certificate, and the owner, from there I was able to workout where to find the original locally.

Answer (score 0):

by mistake I was generating in debug and uploading it so make sure you are uploading release type from build.gradle !