# Uploading signed apk on playstore

Tags: android, google-play

When i am going to upload the updated signed apk of my app then it gives me error i.e."You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): "

What should i do in this case?

Comment: yes,  you have to used same keystore which is used earlier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is accruing because you have used another `keystore` for the new version of the app while the older version was signed with another key store.

In order to give update to your apps you must sign your app with same key store when generating signed `APK`, otherwise you can't give update.

Comment: i am using the same keystore ... if not then hows the signed apk have been generated

Comment: your not using the same `keystore`,  that is only reason play store has given you warning. you might have recreated the `keystore` with same name and password but its not the same `keystore`. you have to find your old `keystore` and signed your updated app with it.

Comment: how should i get my keystore back from my old apk on playstore?

Comment: you can't, otherwise anybody with your apk can get your `keystore`.

Comment: there is nothing you can do but to find the old `keystore`,

Comment: thanks, i had recreated the keystore . Now i am using the old one. So, it works.