# Google Store: How to safely prepare an app for future updates?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, android-keystore

**THE SITUATION:**

At the moment of updating my app in the Google Play Store i got this error message:

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs.
```

Similar situation of an already asked question:

[The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

In my case is not a problem. I am still in development and I also needed to change the package name.

So I have unpublished that app and uploaded a new one.

**THE QUESTION:**

The point is this:

Since i am making a brand new publishing to the Google Play Developer Console, how can I make sure to always be able to update my app?

I have read this warning:

> Keep your **keystore** and **private key** in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

But practically what exactly I have to do?

Should I store my-release-key.keystore in a safe place?

What about the private key? 
How can I know the exact private key I am using?

**THE CODE:**

This is how i create the .apk:

```
cordova build --release android

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias MY_ALIAS_NAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore ./platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk MY_ALIAS_NAME

/usr/local/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.0-preview/zipalign -v 4 ./platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk MY_APP_NAME.apk
```

Is everything fine with it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1-Package name cannot change if it uploaded on playstore once

2-keystore cannot change keep it on safe place for further use in future

3-if you forget the password of keystore it can change

4-give all require permissions in first update so that user will auto update app when new update will come on playstore otherwise google play again ask to user for updating app

Comment: Keystore: I should store the actual file my-release-key.keystore right?
And what about the private key? No need to worry about it?

Comment: save also keystore.jks file which u create for generate signed apk
that file will use further for uploading apk on playstore