# Unable to update android app

Tags: java, android, cordova, apk

I used cordova to build version 1 of my app. Now i rework the app in order to add some back-end using android. Using android studio IDE. I use the same **package name**, **increment version number** and **exact key** to update my app.But i get the following error.Is the IDE makes a difference ?
What is the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the file extension from the keystore file and i tried to build release version. It works flawlessly.
Originally it was example.**keystore** I removed .keystore extension.

Answer (score 2):

Generate new SHA key as this problem arise when debug.keystore file is deleted in any build process.
You can generate key using:
[SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

Update SHA key against your app API key package.

Comment: After generating doesn't google play consider it as new app ?

Comment: No,it just mark as a new identification of your machine.You can delete debug.keystore any time to get new SHA key for the system.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using debug certificate to build apk. Check profile you are using to make apk.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same debug.keystore file and credentials as the first time you uploaded the APK.

Find it, or you are going to need to change the package name and re-upload, re-create all the necessary things in Google Play Console.

Here you have an SO link that explains the same problem. [Link to SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.