# Can we use multiple windows machines to generate singed APK for the same KEY-STORE for a same application package?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

I have created one Keystore using my old machine.

Using this machine i have developed one application and signed it.
Also I have placed this app in the PlayStore.

Now I wanted to use my code from old machine to a new machine.

Also I wanted to give more updates to my app in Google Play.
I have copied the KEYSTORE and signed it from the new machine.
But Google Play is not accepting the file , says the signature is different.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the keystore is same with same key alias ,You should not have any problem .Check if you have different key alias on that keystore.Select the one you used earlier.

Comment: @sunilsunny thats same, still its not accepting. I have used ADT in old machine and this time in new machine Im using Studio , is that a problem ?

Comment: No there should not be any problem with that. Make sure your keystore is not corrupted.Try copying the same file again.How are you generating signed apk..? By storing path to keystore in gradle or manually.Try manually under build tab. Also try answers in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version.

Comment: one more thing if you use 32bit to generate Keystore and 64bit windows machine to sign the apk , will that affect ?