# Illegal option: keystore keytool -genkeypair [OPTION]... Error

Tags: android, terminal, keystore

I'm trying to generate a keystore with these line of code

```
keytool -genkey -v keystore app-key.keystore alias app-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

but showing

```
Illegal option: keystore
keytool -genkeypair[OPTION]...
```

is this a new error?
I'm using mac terminal and trying to deploy android in google playstore

Comment: Why don't use Android studio to generate the Keystore file!

Comment: sorry I don't have enough memory to download android studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your command, you are missing a few "-" before `keystore` & `alias`

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore app-key.keystore 
    -alias app-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Here are all the legal options for `keytool -genkey` usage, please note that "-" is required for valid usage:

```
-alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
-keyalg <keyalg>                key algorithm name
-keysize <keysize>              key bit size
-sigalg <sigalg>                signature algorithm name
-destalias <destalias>          destination alias
-dname <dname>                  distinguished name
-startdate <startdate>          certificate validity start date/time
-ext <value>                    X.509 extension
-validity <valDays>             validity number of days
-keypass <arg>                  key password
-keystore <keystore>            keystore name
-storepass <arg>                keystore password
-storetype <storetype>          keystore type
-providername <providername>    provider name
-providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
-providerarg <arg>              provider argument
-providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
-v                              verbose output
-protected                      password through protected mechanism
```

You may bring up these list of options any time by running

```
keytool -genkey -help
```

Comment: After trying to create new apk and upload it, it shows error:

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

SHA1 *****
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
SHA1 *****


What should I do?

Comment: @Jaze . sorry to hear that. For that new problem you will want to locate the keystore that was previously used for those older apks. This question is similar to your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version

Comment: thank you, my bad, I don't know how to re-use or renew old apk @petey