# How to update Google Play Signed Apk from other than play-store (website etc)

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I uploaded an *apk* signed with my keystore to Google play with accidentally enabling **Google App Signing** option.
I have same *apk* uploaded at my website.

Now, Due to **Google App Signing** option, both *apks* have different signature

1. *Google Play Apk* : Signed by Google
2. *Website Apk* : Signed by my key

which is causing [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version) on update.

**Q) How can I make my Website-apk signed with same signature as Google-Play-signed-apk?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good question.
Unfortunately there is no way to use the final key provided by Google App Signing and generate your own apk with these key, its use is only internal by google to publish in the store.**

> Important: App Signing opt-in is permanent Google Play App Signing is
>   an optional program. If you prefer, you can continue managing your own
>   keys.
>
> Once you've enrolled your app in Google Play App Signing, withdrawal
>   is not supported. To preserve the security of your app signing keys,
>   we don't have the ability to remove keys from the secure server.

Here's more information:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

**I'd suggest you to simply extract the apk provided by the Play Store** (there are a lot of tools or apps to achieve that), **and upload it to your website, or redirect to the Play Store page of your app.**

***Regards.***

Comment: what about a case, where apk needs to be uploaded on website first rather than playstore...

Comment: Since you activated the Google App Signing you need to only use these provided sign. The previous versions must be uninstalled. "Once you've enrolled your app in Google Play App Signing, withdrawal is not supported. To preserve the security of your app signing keys, we don't have the ability to remove keys from the secure server."

Comment: Where from do you extract the APK? From the Play store or from device after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it works:

You have X, your original app signing key that's used to sign the APK that's installed on user's devices - you gave this to Google when you enabled the "App Signing" feature.

You also have Y, the upload key - you use this to sign the APK that you upload to the Play Store.

Google Play will remove the Y signature from the APK you gave it, and will sign the APK with X and send it to the user.

For the APK you want to upload to your website, you need to sign with X

Never lose X, store it in a secure place (like Lastpass Secure notes).