# What is difference between signature and certificate in apk file?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, signature

I know a certificate contains a public key and some extra info (I hope) but is it saved in the apk file? Is it a file or text or what? And what is a signature exactly?
And in Android which one could we easily read to verify the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile your `APK`, one of final steps is signing your `APK`. Actually it is adding 3 small files. You can rename any `APK` to `ZIP`, unpack it and you will find directory `META-INF` - it your signing information.

`MANIFEST.MF` and `CERT.SF` is very similar and contains list of files and their sha1/sha256 hash sums (one for files, second just for entries of first file), and `CERT.RSA` which is `x509` certificate with your public key.

Comment: Cert.rsa contains certificate? What is a signature? When installing an app, Android check app signature, right?

Comment: The statement "Actually it is adding 3 small files" is not really an accurate description of what signing an APK means. When an APK is signed, it's content is encrypted with the private key and can be decrypted with the public key (contained in the apk).
More info:
https://source.android.com/security/apksigning
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Answer (score 7):

**Certificates and keystores**

A public-key certificate, also known as a digital certificate or an identity certificate, contains the public key of a public/private key pair, as well as some other metadata identifying the owner of the key (for example, name and location). The owner of the certificate holds the corresponding private key.

When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key certificate to the APK. The public-key certificate serves as as a "fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK to you and your corresponding private key. This helps Android ensure that any future updates to your APK are authentic and come from the original author. The key used to create this certificate is called the app signing key.

A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys.

Every app must use the same certificate throughout its lifespan in order for users to be able to install new versions as updates to the app. For more about the benefits of using the same certificate for all your apps throughout their lifespans, see Signing Considerations below.

**Sign your debug build**

When running or debugging your project from the IDE, Android Studio automatically signs your APK with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords.

Because the debug certificate is created by the build tools and is insecure by design, most app stores (including the Google Play Store) will not accept an APK signed with a debug certificate for publishing.

Android Studio automatically stores your debug signing information in a signing configuration so you do not have to enter it every time you debug. A signing configuration is an object consisting of all of the necessary information to sign an APK, including the keystore location, keystore password, key name, and key password. You cannot directly edit the debug signing configuration, but you can configure how you sign your release build.

For more information about how to build and run apps for debugging,

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can you finish your last sentence, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (I'm fairly new to android development), you sign your apk with a certificate. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is some additional information:
https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Also, if you want to publish via google play store, this is important to know for you:
[The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)