# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, apk, sha1, code-signing-certificate

Getting error

> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:

I have published an app 4 months ago, now when i try to update and publish it i am getting this error.

Screenshot

[image]

app signing page in google play developer console

[image]

I believe i am using the same keystore after app signing.

Comment: This error occurs if you use a different keystore than you used for that app when you publish the app on Play Store.

Comment: Hopefully you will find the same one, if not, yo won't be able to update it, you might need to create another release for a 'different' (another name) app

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version?rq=1). This question is a duplicate.