# Lost Certificate

Tags: android, google-play

I have lost the original certificate and google play store is not allowing me to upload the apk signed with a new certificate.

i have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version) now and realize that I cant be saved.

I have not lost much of user base or reviews till now (luckily) but its distributed the link to quite some people now.

So, as a solution, if i delete from the app from play store (unpublish) and try to upload with the **same** **package name** and **App name**, will Google allow me to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, signatures are set forever after your first publish to any channel. You'll have to create a new app with a new ID in order to get your correctly-signed app on the market.

Answer (score 1):

No, Google will not allow it. You must use a new package name for the new app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a new package name to upload the app. 
Package names for app files are unique and permanent. Package names cannot be deleted or re-used in the future. Keep in mind that if you've lost your keystore, you'll have to publish the app with a new package name and a new key. You should also update the description of the original app and unpublish it.

[Reference](http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Uploading_Apps_to_Google_Market)