# APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs

Tags: android, google-play, sha

I need help in android application created in eclipse which is already live BUT it has some complication so we had recreate this project on Android studio.After complete debug testing, Now client is trying to make the new apk live by upgrading previous live apk. AND while doing this, client getting following error,

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to
>   your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing
>   APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): [ SHA1:
>   52:D5:6D:B3:88:30:B7:88:3F:4D:8B:D5:37:67:FF:E1:93:7A:E9:89 ] and the
>   certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: B1:53:ED:20:41:2E:1F:0E:1F:5B:54:F3:8D:44:7C:59:AC:EE:FE:DB
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ].

I googled the solution for this error but not found any proper solution. Can you please guide me for resolving the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Comment: Please reformat your question and describe what you have tried. Thank you!

Comment: Did you use different jks file for release apk? This could be the cause of above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in error description: "You must use the same certificate". Seems you generate signed apk using different from old version certificate (.jks file)