# Uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate-

Tags: android, android-studio

My app is live on play store. I have created my .jks file with Alias name key1.  But when I have tried to update my signed APK on play store,

It throws an error :

> "You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate.
>   You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has
>   fingerprint"

Comment: I answered your question please check

Comment: I have issue related can anyone help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459217/apk-that-is-not-signed-with-the-upload-certificate-google-play-store

Answer (score 4):

You have to use same **.jks** file that you have generated first time when you want to generate Signed apk.

Use **.jks** name same as created first time like **key0** do not change it to **key1**.

> Once you created .jks file and upload the apk to playStore , No need
>   to create again , use same .jks every time. If you create .jks file
>   again & used new .jks then playStore will not accept your .apk .

Only need to change in **build.gradle(Module:app)** :

> you have to increase your below both every time when you want to
>   upload apk on playstore.

```
 versionCode 2
 versionName "1.2"
```

**Reference :** https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks for your interest, But Am using same .jks file....in fact i have already updated 16 versions of my app.

Comment: Still are you getting issue ? @NiraliDesai

Comment: yes, let me explain in deep. I have created my .jks with alis name "key1". Am using every time this only. Now for my new version suddenly i am getting error this and when i have checked while selecting .jks file, I saw the alias name changed to "key0"..... I have tried all altername way but didn't find any solution. If you have any other then please help me.

Comment: Signature Version: check both  V1 & V2  & use key1 as you created.

Comment: hey Abhishek.... I have seen this but i can not understand from step 1. If you have an idea then will you explain it here??

Comment: How many times have you updated your app on playstore ?@NiraliDesai

Comment: 17 times--@Abhishek kumar

Comment: Have you used any new thing in this release apk  with your code@NiraliDesai

Comment: only new functionalities of my app and some Crs. But i didn't use anything new for this.

Comment: What is Crs.? Please check again have you using all the thing as previous , I searched this issue is getting only when you used others .jks  or SHA1 key, If the certificate doesn't match like the error message says.@NiraliDesai Also look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version