# APKS cerificate whith fingerprints?

Tags: android, sha1

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

```
[ SHA1: 9E:DF:7F:E1:2E:D2:A2:47:2F:B0:7D:F1:E3:98:D1:03:9B:9D:2F:5D ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: DC:38:7D:1A:C0:DF:1A:CF:70:98:0A:28:12:07:55:DE:B7:Hello,F ]
```

Hello,

I have this problem, I create app whit Seattle could and now this is closed and all my app now no function .... I created a new APK for the android studio, but do I get this error .... how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Use the keystore you used before to sign the new APK. No other option. You can't change your keystore of an app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)