# App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. ERROR

Tags: android

Hello all I have an APP on play store and I uploaded the bundle file first time and kept the keystore save it and then uploaded to playstore. After some time I updated the APP with version 2 and used the keystore app signing key which I created in the first time it got uploaded

But now I am doing the same and the playstore say

> your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
>   app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again

I don't know what to do here, its so bad I am stuck here This is my first APP and I already have this signing issue can you suggest me how to upload the new versions of APP on playstore and fix this signing key issue.

Comment: make sure, keystore you are using is same with the one you signed previous apk, also make sure you are using correct keystore alias while signing and not the other one.

Comment: May be this will helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299302/9868485

Answer (score 0):

Check for the key store you use with the app is correct and no changes made on it.Try again.And also ensure that the key store you are using is of the same app not of any other app.

Answer (score 0):

There a different approaches to overcome this problem. See also the link code4rox provided though nothing of these proposals worked for me and I wasted many days and nerves. My suggestion to you would be:

1. Reset the old keystore with the support of Google Play Developer Support (Play Console)
2. Create a new keystore with your IDE
3. Convert the new keystore to a .pem file with JDK's command line tool "keytool" or use "KeyStore Explorer" (open source GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool and jarsigner)
4. Send the .pem file to Google Play Developer Support.
5. Two days later you can update your App with the new keystore.