# while updating the react native app in play store showing Upload error

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I am trying to update the react native app in the app store I am getting the error with it.

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: EC:FB:46:37:C6:31:90:55:65:F6:46:E4:61:8E:EA:5A:88:0D:72:02 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 5A:4B:97:7A:BA:FD:B5:E5:C0:A5:4A:16:BF:78:E3:9E:EB:2F:8D:CC ]
```

[Error Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vikte.png)

Comment: May be your answer is here : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843261/7271027](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843261/7271027)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you use the wrong Keystore.

I think in your case you 1st sign apk using 1st Keystore and try to upload it on the store.

In the second time, while you sign apk you use another keysore (new keystore) which you use earlier.

This is a reason for this error.

to solve this you have to use keysore which you used at 1st time while generating sign apk.